# Вывод блока "Случайные статьи" на разных страницах сайта

Tags: php, laravel

На сайте есть блок "Случайные статьи", в который выводятся 4 случайные статьи с сайта. Мне нужно выводить этот блок на главной странице, в категориях и на внутренних страницах статей.

Можно ли как-то написать отдельный метод класса, который будет выбирать 4 случайные статьи из БД, подставлять их в вид и выводить на сайт без того, чтобы каждый раз объявлять этот метод в контроллере, который в данный момент используется?

Другими словами, создаем метод **randPosts()** класса **Modules**, затем на главной в нужном месте шаблона вставляем `{{Modules->randPosts()}}`, и в этом месте появляется нужный блок.

Или может есть какое-то более правильное решение данной задачи?

Answer (score 1):

Создайте кастомную директиву `@randPosts`

```
Blade::directive('randPosts', function () {
    $posts = Post::getRandom();
    return view('random-posts-template', compact('posts'));
});
```

и вставляйте в тех view, в которых нужно

```
<div>
    @randPosts
</div>
```

При необходимости различного дизайна на главной / внутренних страницах можно добавить дополнительный параметр.

Подробнее в [документации](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#extending-blade).

Answer (score 0):

Можно, посылай запрос при загрузке страницы на метод нужного контролера через jQuery. Например, `$.get('/randPosts')` или `$.post('/randPosts')`, а можешь Ajax, как умеешь так и делай. Затем получаешь свои посты и уже через jQuery пробегаешь циклом по массиву JSON с постами, оформляешь их как надо под вывод в нужном месте

Answer (score 0):

в вашем случае можно использовать View Composers

Подробнее об этом можно почитать тут [View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#view-composers)